# Ag-grid fullWidthCellRendererFramework adding my own properties

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid for react and wanted to add my own props to the react component I am passing to fullWidthCellRendererFramework. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ag-grid provides a property called context from it's gridOptions. You can place both functions and props there.